# gh-pages redirecting after adding custom domain

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I just added custom domain to my github user pages. it is working perfectly. coming to my other projects and gh-pages, they are redirecting to my custom domain.

`www.mydomain.com` is custom domain added to `myname.github.io`

then my other projects, `myname.github.io/project1` is redirecting to `mydomain.com/project1`

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Heed the `CNAME` entry in your `myname` repo.

Answer (score 1):

As the github documentation points out ([Setting up a custom domain with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages)), you must setup a file called `CNAME` in the project's root-folder, which contains `mydomain.com` or a subdomain. You likely did so already.

Ultimately, you also have a repository `myname`  with a `gh-pages` branch that serves `myname.github.io` or `www.github.com/myname` . Delete the `CNAME` file in here, which will also DNS resolve all other project paths ike `project1`, `project2`.

See [this example](https://github.com/lsauer/lsauer.github.com).

Also [see this troubleshoot](https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working).
(I hope this helps && Happy githubbing).

Comment: By deleting CNAME record, How it can serve for domain?

Comment: @Lo Sauer  I am getting similar issue, Please have look at my GIT "https://github.com/kongaraju" --thank you